# How to tell iPhone NSURLConnection to abort

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have an app that makes moderate use of NSURLConnection.  These async calls eventually finish and release properly (it looks like), but sometimes it takes some time for them to finish.

So, there are times when I exit the app, (note, not just sending it the background), that some of these connections are still active.  If I immediately restart the app, the app freezes on startup.  (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions never seems to get called).

While I'm not certain these connections are the issue, it would probably be good to terminate or cancel any remaining.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Bonus points on how to debug the restart also.  (I'm already saving NSLog statements to a downloadable file)

Comment: It seems the startup issue only happens in the debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cancel any NSURLConnection by sending it a cancel command.

`[connection cancel];`

From Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Cancels an asynchronous load of a
>   request. Once this method is called,
>   the receiver’s delegate will no longer
>   receive any messages for this
>   NSURLConnection.

Your start up issue could be related but hard to tell without knowing what type of data you're downloading and how you are using it.

Comment: This is basically what I found out also.  However, as in cases like mine, I'll need to keep a dynamic list of active connections, so when the time comes, you know which ones to cancel.

Comment: @jahmic Same problem here, i too have to manage image loading on tableview cell via NTLM and confused how to close the particular connection.

Comment: @dip This was a while ago.  So the details are fuzzy, but I seem to recall keeping an array of all the connections and periodically cycling through it and checking each of the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling release on the connection. Maybe it doesn't call shutdown or close on the socket until the last reference is dropped. I do something like this with no issues with references.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
[request release];
```

Comment: yes, upon the delegate notifications of finished or fail, release is called.  But what I mean is, rather then wait for the async calls to finish, tell them to abort now. possible?

Answer (score 0):

For cancel last request : **[NSURLConnection cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];**

For cancel any specific request : **[request cancel];**
Note: Here request is the instance of NSURLConnection